# The antiquity of man

Tags: anthropology

What are the oldest fossils of modern man? What is the evidence until now? I do not ask to know the evolutionary 
chain that led to *H. sapiens*, but I wouldn't mind to hear it, nevertheless.

What are the official sources, like peer reviewed journals, confirming it?

I wish for reference and rigorous scientific analysis.

Comment: Welcome the Biology.SE! First of all, this is **not** a chatroom. It is a Q&A website. Second of all, from a simple web search, I have found [this](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anatomically_modern_human) so I am flagging as a homework question with no research effort. Sometimes you need to learn how to make the best search. This is an example of when that is necessary. I don't know what you searched but I simply searched "oldest fossils of homo sapiens" and got many results. If you want to find peer-reviewed articles, you can use Google Scholar (probably with the same search term).

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. It very much depend on what you call `modern man`. I think this  [wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_human_evolution_fossils) will answer your question. Does it? The wikipedia article also contain the references you might be looking for.

Comment: Can you guys try and do better than Wikipedia?

Comment: @AMR The term modern human is slightly unclear and the wikipedia article is very complete. You did not do a better job than wikipedia.

Comment: In addition to that, understanding why the OP did not get the answer he was looking for from the wikipedia article will inform us of what was unclear to him.

Comment: @AMR the wikipedia article contains a large number of citations from peer-reviewed literature, is clearly laid out, accessible (unlike the Science paper that was your only citation), and points to a great number of other sources for reading. I see nothing wrong with it at all.

Comment: @MattDMo by removing the OPs reference to "Homo sapiens sapiens or Homo sapiens in general" you removed the fact that they understood that there are distinctions to the classifications of modern man. If you look at the Wiki article you will see that a number of the references are to Chris Stringer, the author I reference. And if you look at the title "Genetic and fossil evidence for the origin of modern humans." pretty much sounds like the right starting point for the OP, as they were not interested in other Hominids. And the 918 articles that reference that article will likely have an answer

Answer (score 2):

Try this article as a starting point;

[Stringer, Chris B., and Peter Andrews. "Genetic and fossil evidence for the origin of modern humans." Science 239.4845 (1988): 1263-1268](http://www.sciencemag.org/content/239/4845/1263.short).

It is old, but it has been **[cited 918 times](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cites=1890913100614665906&as_sdt=5,33&sciodt=0,33&hl=en)** to date. That should be more than enough of a breadcrumb trail to find what you are looking for. Also if you click through to the Science Magazine page, it also has a list of relevant articles below the abstract. You may need a membership to AAAS or library access to get a copy of the actual article.

Also try a **Google Scholar** search for **[Modern Human Fossil Record](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&q=Modern%20Human%20Fossil%20Record&btnG=&as_sdt=1%2C33&as_sdtp=)**. The above article is the second article referenced in this search.

Comment: I am well aware of the suggested sources of info.

Comment: Then it was pointless for you to ask your question and waste people's time.

Comment: amr I am only learning this site. I have not finished my comment

Comment: When I posted for the first time my question apparently to a wrong sector, I was just explaining my frustration that there really is scant info on the web on this subject.   I mean where are your anthropology journals? Where are their guidelines and key questions regarding their field of scientific inquiry. I am not doing any homework, though my field of interest is related(health sciences).   So I ask for recent info from an established authority on the field.  Thank you for your responses anyway.

Comment: When you press enter , zoop comment posted. Do you understand now AMR?

Comment: I mean if I want to know for heart failure, or valvular heart disease, I will find authoritative info in a straightforward and open manner , from European Heart Journal, Circulation and Journal of the American College of Cardiology. I don't have even to do any googling. If I try to find info on anthropology on such a key question in their field, I don't have such luck.

Comment: And I can't help but point to the fact that though a newbie to this place I was faced from the beginning with somewhat hostile intentions; I would not be truthful if I didn't  say this.  How is a question "what is the content of water in human blood" answered and considered acceptable? Isn't this supposed to be an old knowledge and not so vague and uncertain like mine? Isn't this readily available through search engines? Does it not look like a homework question? Has that person made efforts to find answers? Please! In that sense almost any question asked in this sector has these attributes

Comment: you accuse me of

Comment: Major anthropological discoveries rise to the level of General interested, so you will often find those article going to the highest impact Journals such as Nature, Science, Proceedings of the National Academy of Sciences, The Philosophical Transactions of The Royal Society, The Royal Anthropology Institute, and so on. If you search Anthropology + those journal names, you will find resources such as http://anthropology.pnas.org and https://www.therai.org.uk. You also have museums such as American Museum of Natural History or The British Museum.

Comment: And I actually took the time to answer your question, so if you were already aware of what I gave you then you already had an answer to your question. All you really needed to do was look at the Journals that the those articles were in or look at their reference lists and the articles citing them and you could have established a pretty extensive list of the journals that cover anthropology. If I wanted to find out about Coronary Artery Diseases I might start in JAMA or NEJM, find a review on the topic, then go down the list of references to find the more specialized material. That's research.

Comment: I appreciate your answer, as pna.org was not an evident source of such material.

Comment: But, being a cardiologist I might add that trying to find an expert opinion on the heart is far easier, and done quickly and  with a greater degree of confidence. On the other hand, such info I requested, is not readily available and you have to have a fore knowledge about where to search. Anyway, I don't see why I "should" research extensively about a difficult subject(I did search and found unsatisfactory sources) , while I regularly see naive questions being posted and answered without fuss or qualms.